# Auto-completion for Stat ET / Eclipse?

Tags: r, ide

after using sciviews-K for a while, I am about to give the R Eclipse combo another chanced. I updated to Helios on my Mac OS X Snow Leopard. So far everything that used to make trouble with Eclipse works, but somehow I miss the auto-completion of code. Or at least the standard suggestion of paramaters when you use R functions. This is even possible in the standard R GUI.

How can I use some of these enhancements with StatET Eclipse?

Thx in advance for not telling me to use Emacs / ESS !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can't have an answer shorter than 15 characters, so here is some elaborate text to pass this silly check. Try pressing `Ctrl+Space`.

Comment: cool, this works! probably you will gain some more points in that keystrokes per accepted answer stat despite the elaborate text :)